# Find homogneous solution to pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to find the homogenous solution and fixed points to this pde. I have no idea how to proceed.

$$
\partial_t u = r u - (\partial_{xx}u +1)^2u - u^3
$$

It is second order non linear parital differential equation

Comment: It's not really a PDE unless there are derivatives involving more than one variable. All I see is spatial derivatives in $x$.

Comment: sorry. i typed `d_x` instead of  `d_t`

Comment: @Mattos can you help me with this ?